# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)'

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I get data from model file in array, and that array to next vc.

When I am using try to use the code, I'm facing the following problem:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of
>   type '(Int?)'

```
extension Invoiceview:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        invoicetableviewhight.constant = CGFloat(30*Orderdata.count)
        return Orderdata.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvoiceTableViewCell")as! InvoiceTableViewCell
        let model = Orderdata[indexPath.row]
        cell.ordertype.text = model.prodName
        cell.orderprice.text = String(model.price)






        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this error?

Comment: safely unwrap the int and pass it to the string initializer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update

```
cell.orderprice.text = String(model.price)
```

with

```
if let priceOfProduct = model.price {
   cell.orderprice.text = String(priceOfProduct )
}
else{
   cell.orderprice.text = "";
}
```